# How to change syntax coloring for JavaScript files in Automator Dark Mode?

Tags: macos, catalina, automator, dark-mode

In Automator on macOS 10.15.7, Javascript code is too dark when using Dark Mode:

[image]

Is there a way to change the colors?

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by enabling the light theme for just the Automator app.

In your terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.Automator NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool Yes
```

Details here: https://webtrickz.com/disable-dark-mode-for-specific-app-on-mac/